# Fill SQLContext with data from MongoDB in Spark with Java

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to prepare a Java class that will read an index from MongoDB into an SQLContext in order to get a Dataset to process in Spark.My code is as follows

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Aggregation").setMaster("local");
conf.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");
conf.set("mongo.input.uri", uri);
conf.set("mongo.output.uri", uri);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
options.put("host", mongoHost +":27017");
options.put("inferSchema", "true");
options.put("database", database);
Dataset df = sqlContext.read().format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").options(options).option("collection", "kpi_aggregator").load();
```

I use the following dependencies in maven

```
        <!-- Spark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stratio.datasource</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mongodb_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

However when I execute the code I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: w >= 0
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrueArgument(Assertions.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.WriteConcern.<init>(WriteConcern.java:316)
    at com.mongodb.WriteConcern.<init>(WriteConcern.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern$.<init>(WriteConcern.scala:41)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern$.<clinit>(WriteConcern.scala)
    ... 43 more
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: This guy has the same issue - [probably compatibility issue](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB/issues/147#issuecomment-232007394)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by **removing** `com.stratio.datasource` **dependency** and changing my code as follows:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Aggregation").setMaster("local");
conf.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");
conf.set("mongo.input.uri", uri);
conf.set("mongo.output.uri", uri);    
conf.set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner","MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
options.put("uri", uri);
options.put("database", database);

Dataset df = MongoSpark.read(sqlContext).options(options).option("collection", "kpi_aggregator").load();
```

Comment: Just to note: `conf.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");` isn't used by the Mongo Spark Connector.